# How do I get a Maximise button and a What's This button on a Qt Dialog?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt4

I currently have a Qt::Dialog with a What's This help button, and a close button in the title bar.

I tried modifying the window hint flags to include the maximise and minimise buttons as well.
This worked but removed the What's This button, even if I explicitly included the flag for the what's this button as well.

Is there any way that I can have a dialog with maximise and minimise buttons but keep the What's this functionality?

Comment: I contacted Digia regarding this issue, and they informed me that it was a bug with Windows where the window manager (the thing that actually draws the title bar) will ignore the what's this hint if there is a maximise button set.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind where the What's this button appears, you can create a new button anywhere (probably called "What's This" or just "?").

This new button must be connected to a slot that includes the function:

```
`QWhatsThis::enterWhatsThisMode();`
```

which will perform the same function as the now missing What's This button in the title bar.
It probably is the only function the slot needs to call.

This action can even be called from a menu, and if required from a key combination.